# writing stored procedure using case when

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that involves a lot of case when statements. I have a condition(when y=1, 10 more if conditions inside it), similarly for y=2 and y=3. I was trying to see if it could be simplified.

well, my application page has a drop down list with 3 options when i select either one of that, then i had a choice to select another 10 options in separate drop down list. So, i am trying to call my stored procedures in that page. thanks.

```
set @where = case
           when @y = 1
           then
              case
              when @value=1
              then
                  //do something
              else @ value =2
              then
                     //do something
              ... repeat then statement 8 more times
           when @y=2
              //10 time check conditions    
           when @ y =3
              //repeat again with @value condition 10 times
          end
```

Comment: write three separate sp for 1, 2 and 3 and just call these functions in your main proc.

Comment: If you have a lot of values to values mapping, you can store them in a table and do some lookups. It's not as efficient as your case statement. Unless you can simplify the logic, your options to simplify the statement are limited.

Comment: so how can I achieve this if I did case when @y between 1 and 3, repeat 10 conditions because same if else condition logic applies to each y.

Comment: Is your stored procedure dymanically building a tsql string and executing it?

Comment: yes, I need to attach the condition to where clause dynamically when either of the condition is satisfied.

Comment: I think we'd offer better advice if you showed all of the sproc for context or made shorter example that still demonstrated the problem.

Comment: I agree - we would need to see what's in the **//DoSomething** part to determine what could be worked out with a formula.

Comment: A small improvement is to use the simpler syntax of the case statement. CASE @y WHEN 1 THEN //do somehting  WHEN 2 THEN // do something